# How to unite Promises into one Promise in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await

I need to return temp_data after it will be fulfilled with data after .map however, now it always returns undefined value as I'm doing this: let temp_data: LooseObject = {}. But without this, I am not able to use LooseObject. Is there any hack that will help me to solve this problem?

```
    async getData(){
        let temp_data: LooseObject = {}
        this.categorylist.map((category: string) => {
            this.getByCategory(category).then((newsList) => {
                temp_data[category] = []
                newsList.forEach((article: Article) => {
                    temp_data[category].push(article)
                })
                console.log('Data: ',temp_data)
            })
        })
        
        return await temp_data
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is an example of my getByCategory function:

```
async getByCategory(category: string) {
         const news = await this.newsapi.v2.topHeadlines({
            q: category,
            sortBy: 'popularity'
        })
         return await news.articles.map(this._transformArticle)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it by using a reduce function and await Promise.all of the returned array of promises.

Comment: where should I use it? I have watched a few manuals and didn't find any good explanation.

Comment: Here is a good example: https://gist.github.com/anvk/5602ec398e4fdc521e2bf9940fd90f84

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you have a working example (could be mock) of the getByCategory function? Would help me in showing you what I mean :)